# How to change video speed (1x,2x ....) in Expo av?

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, expo, expo-av

I am trying implement a video functionality on Expo using Expo-av. But I got stuck in controlling video speed like 1x, 2x like youtube. Can any one help me on that .
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can control it with the rate parameter inbuilt in expo-av

```
<Video
  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
  rate={1.0} //CHANGE ME
  volume={1.0}
  isMuted={false}
  resizeMode="cover"
  shouldPlay
  isLooping
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```